# query not executing in .net

Tags: .net, ms-access

```
 Private Sub Apply_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    If Not passid = Nothing Then
        Call connection()

        Dim query As String = ("SELECT * FROM [Applicationform] WHERE [ID]= " & passid)
        Dim dbsource As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Dormandb.accdb"
        Dim conn = New OleDbConnection(dbsource)
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, conn)
        conn.Open()


        Try
            Dim read As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            read.Read()


            fname.Text = read.Item("FamilyName").ToString
            gname.Text = read.Item("GivenName").ToString
            mname.Text = read.Item("MiddleName").ToString
            Age.Text = read.Item("Age").ToString
            'if db = null , radiobutton.checked = false
            If IsDBNull(read("Sex")) Then
                rad_female.Checked = False
                rad_male.Checked = False
            Else
                If read.Item("Sex") = "Male" Then
                    rad_male.Checked = True
                Else
                    rad_female.Checked = True
                End If
            End If

            If IsDBNull(read("Date of Birth")) Then
                DateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now
            Else
                DateTimePicker1.Value = read.Item("Date of Birth").ToString
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

> i have two sql query's in this form , and when i compile it everything is working for the first query but, for the second query its just not working. i tried looking for query errors in the console but there's none.

```
Private Sub Submit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Submit.Click
    Dim dte As String = DateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString()
    Dim gendr As String = ""
    If rad_female.Checked Then
        gendr = rad_female.Text

    ElseIf rad_male.Checked Then
        gendr = rad_male.Text
    Else
        gendr = ""
    End If


    Call connection()
    Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO [Applicationform] ([FamilyName],[GivenName],[MiddleName],[Age],[Sex],[Date of Birth],[Place of Birth],[Religion],[Address],[Province],[EmailAdd],[LandlineNo],[MobileNo],
                            [Father'sName],[F Age],[F Address],[F Occupation],[F EmailAdd],[F ContactNo],[Mother'sName],[M Age],[M Address],[M Occupation],[M EmailAdd],[M ContactNo])
                            VALUES (@fname,@gname,@mname,@Age,@Sex,@dob,@place,@reli,@address,@prov,@emaddd,@landline,@mobile,@Father,@fAge,@fAdd,@fOcc,@fEmadd,@fCon,@Mother,@mAge,@mAdd,@mOcc,@mEmadd,@mCon)"
    Dim dbsource As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Dormandb.accdb"

    Dim conn = New OleDbConnection(dbsource)
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, conn)

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", fname.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gname", gname.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mname", mname.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", Age.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sex", gendr)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", dte)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@place", place.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reli", reli.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", address.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prov", prov.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emaddd", emaddd.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@landline", landline.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobile", mobile.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Father", Father.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fAge", fAge.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fAdd", fAdd.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fOcc", fOcc.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fEmadd", fEmadd.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fCon", fCon.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mother", Mother.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mAge", mAge.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mAdd", mAdd.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mOcc", mOcc.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mEmadd", mEmadd.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mCon", mCon.Text)

    conn.Open()

    Try
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Account Created")
        fname.Clear()
        gname.Clear()
        mname.Clear()
        Age.Clear()
        place.Clear()
        reli.Clear()
        address.Clear()
        prov.Clear()
        emaddd.Clear()
        landline.Clear()
        mobile.Clear()
        Father.Clear()
        fAge.Clear()
        fAdd.Clear()
        fOcc.Clear()
        fEmadd.Clear()
        fCon.Clear()
        Mother.Clear()
        mAge.Clear()
        mAdd.Clear()
        mOcc.Clear()
        mEmadd.Clear()
        mCon.Clear()
        rad_female.Checked = False
        rad_male.Checked = False
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message())


    End Try


End Sub
```

> the if condition on the second block of codes works properly, but the query does not.

Comment: Can you describe what "not work properly" means? Do you get any errors from compiling? Running? From the database? Does it just not insert records?

Comment: no the console does not give any errors and/or the (msgbox(ex)) does not return any errors too. 
the second query was suppose to send data on ms-access database, but when i execute it the values does not send to db.

Comment: " its just not working" - what actually happens? or doesn't happen? what is the symptom here?

Comment: it *sounds* like the symptom is : it is running without error, but when you look, no record has been inserted. Since you're using a file-based provider, an important questions is: **where are you looking?** Note: if you have a database file in your solution tree, that is *not* the file that gets edited; when you run your app, the build output (including the database file) are usually *copied* to a run location. A very common error is to look for changes in the database file in the solution tree, rather than the one in the build output location. Completely different copy of the data.

Comment: So i should look for the changes, in the main db file rather than the solution explorer?